# Powershell Windows Apps get Publisher Display Name

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-store-apps

hope someone can help me out.

Iam trying to get a listing of every Windows App installed on my Computer. With Powershell it is easy to get a complete list

```
Get-AppxPackage
```

the result looks like:

```
Name              : Amazon.com.Amazon
Publisher         : CN=5050E920-F712-4A72-AFD4-2E82CC365EEF
Architecture      : Neutral
ResourceId        : 
Version           : 3.1.2.7
PackageFullName   : Amazon.com.Amazon_3.1.2.7_neutral__343d40qqvtj1t
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Amazon.com.Amazon_3.1.2.7_neutral__343d40qqvtj1t
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : Amazon.com.Amazon_343d40qqvtj1t
PublisherId       : 343d40qqvtj1t
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
Dependencies      : {Amazon.com.Amazon_3.1.2.7_neutral_split.language-de_343d40qqvtj1t}

Name              : 34791E63.CanonOfficePrinterUtility
Publisher         : CN=41BAE105-1234-432C-A39C-1B7D1C24232B
Architecture      : Neutral
ResourceId        : 
Version           : 1.0.0.0
PackageFullName   : 34791E63.CanonOfficePrinterUtility_1.0.0.0_neutral__6e5tt8cgb93ep
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\34791E63.CanonOfficePrinterUtility_1.0.0.0_neutral__6
                    e5tt8cgb93ep
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : 34791E63.CanonOfficePrinterUtility_6e5tt8cgb93ep
PublisherId       : 6e5tt8cgb93ep
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
```

my Problem is.. how can i get the Name of the Publisher.. the Publisher field is sometimes a Path (CN=....) and sometimes a GUID.

Is it possible to find out which Publisher has which Id? or is there another way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You could get the publisher display name from the package manifest, provided the publisher bothered to fill in the manifest fields properly:

```psh
Get-AppxPackage | Get-AppxPackageManifest | % {
  $_.Package.Properties.PublisherDisplayName
}
```

On my system there are several packages whose manifest has just a generic `ms-resource:PublisherDisplayName` as the publisher display name.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the app name, you can ask for it:

```
Get-AppxPackage | % {  $_.Name }
```